# How to change the menu icon in the latest Raspbian buster on Pi 3?

Tags: menu, icons, raspberry-pi3, raspbian-buster

I need to change the menu button icon on the latest Raspbian OS (Buster). I tried to change it by right clicking on the button itself and brought up the menu editor. Then, clicked on the preference button menu button. On that popup window, there is no browse button to select the image you want to apply to your menu button. So, how can you change the menu icon on the latest Raspbian OS (buster)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with Pi OS Buster (Debian 10.11). Entering the image path in the popup window wouldn't work, so I searched for the image itself or a link to it. Sadly I didn't find any links so I am not able to enter a path where my icon is located. But I found the images and you can replace them.

There are four versions of the menu icon for the sizes 16x16, 24x24, 32x32 and 48x48 in `/usr/share/icons/PiXflat/48x48/places/` (replace the 48x48 with the previously mentioned formats)

Depending on your taskbar symbol size (default in my version was 36px) the matching image is used. So I replaced the `start-here.png` with my icon in **every format** and it worked.

Here is an example for the 24x24 format with my image located in the home directory.

```
cd /usr/share/icons/PiXflat/24x24/places/
sudo mv start-here.png start-here_backup.png
sudo cp ~/menu.png ./start-here.png
```

Note: The images for the icon "rpi" are located in `/usr/share/icons/PiXflat/48x48/apps/`

Followup: Pi OS Stretch uses /usr/share/icons/PiX/32x32/apps/launch.png as menu icon. Again depending on your configured icon size.